# Hippo cms and mysql on Glassfish

Tags: mysql, glassfish, hippocms

I have a big problem with the addition of a mysql database to Glassfish. I did all the steps located here http://www.onehippo.org/library/deployment/configuring/configuring-hippo-7-for-mysql.html .

When I use

```
$ mvn clean install
$ mvn -P cargo.run
```

It's looks fine, because in my workspace.xml I have :

```
<FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DbFileSystem">
  <param name="url" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/repositoryDS"/>
  <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
  <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
  <param name="schema" value="mysql"/>
</FileSystem>
```

next I use

```
$ mvn clean install
$ mvn -P dist
```

and deploy created cms.war and site.war to glassfish server (Previously, I copied all the libraries and everything works. Inspired by https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/hippo_tip_deploying_hippo_to ). All of project works fine.

The problem is the database. In new workspace.xml in glassfish (/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/cms/WEB-INF/storage/workspaces/default/workspace.xml) I have:

```
<FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.local.LocalFileSystem">
  <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}"/>
</FileSystem>

<PersistenceManager   class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.pool.H2PersistenceManager">
  <param name="url" value="jdbc:h2:file:${wsp.home}/db"/>
  <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
  <param name="minBlobSize" value="4194304"/>
</PersistenceManager>
```

and server created db.h2.db file in storage/workspace/default, but I need a base in mysql. What can I do wrong?

Additional question. How to check what is in the database? In mysql hippo created something like this:

```
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_hippo    |
+--------------------+
| DATASTORE          |
| DEFAULT_BINVAL     |
| DEFAULT_BUNDLE     |
| DEFAULT_FSENTRY    |
| DEFAULT_NAMES      |
| DEFAULT_REFS       |
| REPOSITORY_FSENTRY |
| VERSION_BINVAL     |
| VERSION_BUNDLE     |    
| VERSION_FSENTRY    |
| VERSION_NAMES      |
| VERSION_REFS       |
+--------------------+
```

There are no tables like "Book" "Author" "Shop". But in server Hippo have all this data which I can edit.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MySQL configuration seems to be fine. You have to keep in mind that the most important thing is that all the configuration needs to be correct in the **repository.xml** file. The **workspace.xml** is generated/extracted out of the repository.xml file once the repository gets initialized for the first time. So if you've deployed Hippo before having the correct settings for MySQL, you might have an old workspace.xml in your directory, which results in the H2 db being used.

The first article you link to contains a section called "Make the repository use this configuration file". This is very important if you want to use your own configuration and not the built-in configuration which leverages the H2 database. If you do not provide this system property the build in configuration will be used.

> Additional question. How to check what is in the database? There are
>   no tables like "Book" "Author" "Shop". But in server Hippo have all
>   this data which I can edit.

Persistence in Jackrabbit is a bit complicated, it makes sense to read the [configuration overview documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/ConfigurationOverview) and [persistence manager documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/PersistenceManagerFAQ) first. The persistence of content and data is handled by an *internal* Jackrabbit component that handles the persistent storage of content nodes and properties. Property values are also stored in the persistence manager, with the exception of large binary values (usually stored inside the datastore).

Comment: At first, thanks for answer

My repository.xml is exactly the same as on the page http://www.onehippo.org/library/deployment/configuring/configuring-hippo-7-for-mysql.html and of course I made the repository use in configuration file "pom.xml"

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Keep in mind that doing this in the pom.xml only changes your local cargo based Tomcat instance and not your glassfish instance. So you need to provide this same system property to your glassfish container.

Comment: Thanks ;) so I'll try to set up my Glassfish instance