# Hippo and Jackrabbit connection

Tags: mysql, jackrabbit, hippocms

For several days trying to get into the database in my project in Hippo. User "Jeroen" told me to read about Jackrabbit ([Hippo cms and mysql on Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28339871/hippo-cms-and-mysql-on-glassfish)).

Now I'm trying connect JCR with "JCR Browser" using default values:

```
Hippo repository via RMI:
  Host : 127.0.0.1
  Port : 1099
  Repository Name : hipporepository

Jackrabbit repository via HTTP:
  Host : localhost
  Port : 8080

Jackrabbit repository via RMI:
  Host : localhost
  Port : 1099
  Repository Name : jackrabbit.repository

Jackrabbit repository via WebDAV:
  URL: http://localhost:8080/jackrabbit-webapp-2.1.0/server
```

and there are my errors :

```
Could not connect to remot Jackrabbit using the following WebDAV URL : http://localhost:8080/jackrabbit-webapp-2.1.0/server
```

It was not possible to login. Please check the credentials

What values are good? Where can I check them?

Mine generated workspace.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Workspace name="default">
<FileSystem class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.fs.db.DbFileSystem">
  <param name="url" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/repositoryDS"/>
  <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
  <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
  <param name="schema" value="mysql"/>
</FileSystem>

<PersistenceManager class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.persistence.bundle.MySqlPersistenceManager">
  <param name="driver" value="javax.naming.InitialContext"/>
  <param name="url" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/repositoryDS"/>
  <param name="schemaObjectPrefix" value="${wsp.name}_"/>
  <param name="externalBLOBs" value="true"/>
  <param name="consistencyCheck" value="false"/>
  <param name="consistencyFix" value="false"/>
</PersistenceManager>

<SearchIndex class="org.hippoecm.repository.FacetedNavigationEngineImpl">
  <param name="indexingConfiguration" value="indexing_configuration.xml"/>
  <param name="indexingConfigurationClass" value="org.hippoecm.repository.query.lucene.ServicingIndexingConfigurationImpl"/>
  <param name="path" value="${wsp.home}/index"/>
  <param name="useCompoundFile" value="true"/>
  <param name="minMergeDocs" value="1000"/>
  <param name="volatileIdleTime" value="10"/>
  <param name="maxMergeDocs" value="1000000000"/>
  <param name="mergeFactor" value="5"/>
  <param name="maxFieldLength" value="10000"/>
  <param name="bufferSize" value="1000"/>
  <param name="cacheSize" value="100000"/>
  <param name="enableConsistencyCheck" value="true"/>
  <param name="autoRepair" value="true"/>
  <param name="analyzer" value="org.hippoecm.repository.query.lucene.StandardHippoAnalyzer"/>
  <param name="queryClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.QueryImpl"/>
  <param name="respectDocumentOrder" value="false"/>
  <param name="resultFetchSize" value="100"/>
  <param name="extractorPoolSize" value="0"/>
  <param name="extractorTimeout" value="100"/>
  <param name="extractorBackLogSize" value="100"/>
  <param name="excerptProviderClass" value="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.query.lucene.DefaultHTMLExcerpt"/>
  <!-- supportHighlighting value is ignored, see REPO-711 -->
  <param name="supportHighlighting" value="false"/>

  <param name="supportSimilarityOnStrings" value="true"/>
  <param name="supportSimilarityOnBinaries" value="false"/>
  <param name="slowAlwaysExactSizedQueryResult" value="false"/>

  <param name="onWorkspaceInconsistency" value="log"/>
  <!-- optional cache parameters for faceted engine. The default size
  when not configured is 1000 for both parameters -->
  <!-- param name="docIdSetCacheSize" value="1000"/>
  <param name="facetValueCountMapCacheSize" value="1000"/-->
</SearchIndex>

<ISMLocking class="org.apache.jackrabbit.core.state.FineGrainedISMLocking"/>
  </Workspace>
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jackrabbit [standalone web application](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/standalone-server.html) only works if you run Jackrabbit standalone jar or war and not if you run Hippo CMS or any other CMS based on Jackrabbit, so I'm afraid this won't work with Hippo CMS. Hippo CMS has it's own JCR browser called the Hippo CMS console and can be reached at http://localhost:8080/cms/console.